# Which way I can forbid editing node labels in TreeView if I want some labels be able to be edited and others no?

Tags: c#, treeview, label, edit, nodes

I set LabelEdit to true and all labels becomes editable.
How I can forbid editing level 0 nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, try canceling the edit in the `BeforeLabelEdit` event:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  treeView1.BeforeLabelEdit += treeView1_BeforeLabelEdit;
}

void treeView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Node.Level == 0) {
    e.CancelEdit = true;
  }
}
```